# Puppet move file with permission 400?

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to use puppet to copy a file:

```
  file{ '/root/.ssh/id_rsa' :
    source =>  'puppet:///modules/certs/.ssh/id_rsa',
  }
```

The permissions are `-r-------- 1 root root`.

If I run `chmod +r` on the file my script works, but with the above permissions puppet fails to copy the file.

> Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[default]/File[/root/.ssh/id_rsa]: Could
>   not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for
>   puppet:///modules/certs/.ssh/id_rsa: Error 500 on SERVER: Server
>   Error: Permission denied -
>   /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/certs/files/.ssh/id_rsa

I assumed puppet would be running as root and thus would be able to copy the file. Is there a way to do this without changing the permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message indicates you're using a master/agent setup. In this kind of setup, the Puppet master (or server) usually runs under the `puppet` user as it's a web application that's simply providing files and catalogs for download.

Only the Puppet agent (on the client) will run as root to make configuration changes to the operating system.

The file on your Puppet master should be readable to the `puppet` user, either by changing ownership:

```
chown puppet id_rsa
```

or giving group read permissions:

```
chgrp puppet id_rsa
chmod g+r id_rsa
```

or giving *other* read permissions, as you did with `chmod +r`.

Note that there are limited authorisation controls over access to the file. Any host with a valid Puppet SSL key/cert will be able to download the file from the Puppet master, even if they don't have the manifest/file configured. This is not a very secure method to distribute private keys.

Comment: Thanks I saw something in Puppet 4 cookbook about properly sharing sensitive data. I will have to find it and re-read. But this will work for my initial proof of concept.

Comment: For future readers hiera-gpg looks like a possible solution for this (Puppet Cookbook, third edition, p. 78).

Comment: [hiera-eyaml](https://github.com/voxpupuli/hiera-eyaml) has now replaced hiera-gpg.